# Click object after drop in jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a box (first box) that stores the items. Those items are droppable to any of the two boxes (second and third) below. After dropping it, I wanted to return those items back to the first box after **clicking** the items (located in second or third box) and remove it where i dropped it.

Does anybody know? Here is my code below:

```
<div class="well">
    <div class="draggable">CONTENT</div>
    <div class="draggable">CONTENT 2</div>
    <div class="draggable">CONTENT 3</div>
</div>
<div id="droppable1" class="well col-md-3" style="z-index:-1;"></div>
<div id="droppable2" class="well col-md-9" style="z-index:-1;"></div>

<script>
$('.draggable').draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: "invalid",  
    containment: "document"   
});


//ui.draggable is the object of dragged item
$('#droppable1, #droppable2').droppable({
    accept: '.draggable',
    drop: function (event, ui) {  
        ui.draggable.remove();
        $(this)
            .append(ui.helper.addClass('test').clone(false).css({
                position: 'relative',
                left: '0px',
                top: '0px',
                color:'red'
            })
        );  
    }
});  
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tq2j4wot/5/

Comment: Updated the answer, try it again, and you can change the css as well when adding to first box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a click event on the dragged element

```
<div class="well" id ="mainWell">
    <div class="draggable">CONTENT</div>
    <div class="draggable">CONTENT 2</div>
    <div class="draggable">CONTENT 3</div>
</div>
<div id="droppable1" class="well col-md-3" style="z-index:-1;"></div>
<div id="droppable2" class="well col-md-9" style="z-index:-1;"></div>


<script>

$('.draggable').draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: "invalid",  
    containment: "document"   
});

$(document).on('click','.draggable',function(){
 $(this).appendTo('#mainWell');
   $(this).draggable({
      helper: 'clone',
      revert: "invalid",  
      containment: "document"   
  });
});
//ui.draggable is the object of dragged item
$('#droppable1, #droppable2').droppable({
    accept: '.draggable',
    drop: function (event, ui) {  
        ui.draggable.remove();
        $(this)
            .append(ui.helper.addClass('test').clone(false).css({
                position: 'relative',
                left: '0px',
                top: '0px',
                color:'red'
            })
        );  
    }
});  
</script>
```

[Working Example Link](http://jsfiddle.net/tq2j4wot/48/)

Comment: Thanks. This is working but the problem is, if i repeat many times, I cannot drag again.

Comment: And on more. If you drop all item in one box and click on one of the item all items will goo back. It also a problem. @smzapp

Answer (score 0):

There are some built-in options for this, on your .draggable(), set the revert option to 'invalid', and it'll go back if it wasn't successfully dropped onto a droppable, like this:

```
$(".draggable").draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });
```

Then in your .droppable() set what's valid for a drop using the accept option, for example:

```
$(".droppable").droppable({ accept: '.draggable' });​
```

Anything not matching this selector gets reset when you let go, you can see a full demo here. The accept option also takes a function if you need filtering a selector can't provide, like this:

```
$(".droppable").droppable({ 
  accept: function(dropElem) {
    //dropElem was the dropped element, return true or false to accept/refuse it
  }
});​
```

Comment: I know these things but what I am asking is , after I dropped the items in second or third boxes, when the user **clicks** the item, it will go back to the first box.

Comment: Please check. http://jsfiddle.net/tq2j4wot/32/ . This is correct already but the problem is, if I click and drag again many times, I can no longer drag.

Comment: @smzapp: Great Job by Jashpreet Singh: http://jsfiddle.net/tq2j4wot/48/